# Writing unit tests for a public method that takes information from a private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I am writing unit tests for methods. In general it seems bad practice (and simply difficult) to write unit tests for private methods.

The methods I am writing unit tests for are public, however some have information acquired from a earlier private method call.

What should be done for cases like this when writing unit tests for the two public methods?

```
public int MyPublicMethod()
{
    //code that doesnt need a private method

    ComplexObject myObj = MyPrivateMethod(data);

    result = otherPublicMethod(myObj);

    //other code using that result
}

public int otherPublicMethod(ComplexObject data)
{
   //code using the data from the private object
}

private ComplexObject MyPrivateMethod(Data data)
{
    //code that returns a complex object
}
```

The only thing I can think of for testing these public methods are to hard code the expected returned values. Is there any other ways for cases like this, or perhaps these methods fit into the same area of "don't test private methods" to be "also don't test public methods that rely on private methods". I imagine its good to test these methods as much as possible to get higher test coverage.

Comment: This may be closed due to it being opinion based.   Private methods in these cases are often used to organize logic, make code more readable, or enable re-use within a class.   *In my opinion*, there's not much value in testing private methods, just test the output of the public functions match your expectations for the inputs you provided.  It shouldn't matter how the public function is implemented.  The one caveat is you would need to know about any external dependencies the private method leverages.

Comment: `In general it seems bad practice (and simply difficult) to write unit tests for private methods` it's not "difficult", it's impossible in C#. And this is for a good reason, because if you are trying to test private methods *you are doing something wrong*.

Comment: To clarify this is for testing a public method that requires information received from a private method, so in a sense does a public method like that fall in the same category as "do not test private methods OR public methods that rely on private methods"

Comment: @Blerdegerb could you please clarify why you think there is a problem with test like  `Assert.AreEqual(42, myObject.MyPublicMethod());` ?

Comment: The actual behavior of private methods shouldn’t matter; the main point of tests is to test the behavior of public methods against known values. You should shift your perspective towards more rigorously validating the public interface rather than trying to control the private one.

Comment: What happens if the public method _doesn't_ get the info it needs from the private method? Is an exception thrown? How would you detect and test for that?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov because for some of these public methods its more like Assert.AreEqual(42, myObject.MyPublicMethod(dataIgotFromAPrivateMethod));
I hope this helps clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, here's how I would think about it:

IMHO all you should care about in a unit test of the public method is *do I get the correct result*. You should not care *how* it gets that result, only that it gives you the correct result. That way, if you want to do it a *different* way, you can verify that your change works by running the unit tests.

Another way to ensure that the private method "works" is to throw an exception if the public method does not get the info it needs. You could even figure out a way to make sure it *doesn't* work and verify that an exception is thrown.

To address the remaining discussion in comments:

Unit tests should (for the most part) test what your users can do, to make sure that results are correct, incorrect inputs are handles properly, etc.  If your users must call `X` before they call `Y` (regardless of whether that is sensible or not), then your unit test should do that, meaning it should verify that `Y` succeeds if `X` is called, and fails it it is not.

*Long Term* if you were to refactor so that the input to `Y` could be obtained by other public means, then your tests should reflect that change.

Comment: That does make sense, however, the problem is that some of these public methods can only be tested because they need information passed in that was acquired by calling a private method. So to call/test this public method I in theory need to call a private method. Or hard code the data which is difficult when dealing with complex objects, so I am unsure if these public methods still get tested since they rely on private methods.

Comment: Oh I see the difference now. I still think it's irrelevant. How to users of the library get `ComplexObject` to pass to the public method? Is _that_ what you really want to test?

Comment: The public method as a whole, in our case "otherPublicMethod", since it takes in a ComplexObject that is retrieved from a private method cant be tested unless we use that private method. So in our case, how could I test the different aspects of the otherPublicMethod because one (or more) parts rely on a private method(s) now we have a technically testable public method untested. The only thing I can think of is to hard code the data that the private method would have possibly returned

Comment: But how do non-private callers of `otherPublicMethod` get a `ComplexObject` to pass to that method?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but in our example MyPublicMethod calls a private method gets the object from that method and passes it into otherPublicMethod

Comment: So a user has to call `MyPublicMethod` before calling `otherPublicMethod`? And that `ComplexObject` is available through other means (i.e. the user has to have a refernce to `ComplexObject` to call `otherPublicMethod` - where do they get that reference)? Is there no other way to get a `ComplexObject` to call `otherPublicMethod` directly?

Comment: "So a user has to call MyPublicMethod before calling otherPublicMethod?" Not necessarily for that part. What does need to happen is that we need to get an instance of that complex object, the way we would do that would be to call "MyPrivateMethod" so that we can call otherPublicMethod. So if we want to write a unit test for otherPublicMethod we in theory have to calla private method in our unit test which we can't do. In theory we could just create a new ComplexObject directly through hardcode but I feel that isn't best practice but I cant think of anything else

Comment: My main point is - you test it by running it the way a user would. If a user has to call `MyPublicMethod` to get `ComplexObject` to then call `otherPublicMethod`, then that should be your test. Maybe that means you can't test `otherPublicMethod` in isolation without constructing or mocking a ComplexObject to give it. But it still seems odd that you have a public method that takes parameters that can't be obtained publicly (at least you haven't shown how to get it)

Comment: Write now I am working with legacy code and I agree its a bit odd. For private methods I understand that we can't and really shouldn't unit test as they are seen as something that should be hidden from the user. But then it is odd to me to then have a public method that can only be tested by either mocking the data or leaving a public method untested.  The real question is, "is there a 3rd option?"

Comment: I mean you _could_ make it `internal` and add `internalsVisibleTo` (there are lots of articles explaining how to do that). But I still claim that _you should test what your users can do_.  If your users have to do `X` before they can do `Y` (regardless of the sensibleness) they your test should be that `Y` succeeds if `X` is done first, and fails if it is not.

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense and I would say answers my question, there are too many pending edits would you add your most recent comment to your answer and I can mark it as "Accepted"? (im getting used to how things are actually done on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You should treat public methods as a black box and only test if it behaves as expected e.g. returns the correct result. You don't need to test private methods, they exist to help make your code readable.

With your current software design you can write 2 unit tests like the following.

```cs
[Fact]
public void PublicMethodShouldReturnCorrectValue()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    
    // act
    var result = sut.MyPublicMethod();
    
    // assert
    result.Should().Be(1);
}

[Fact]
public void OtherMethodShouldReturnCorrectValue()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    var data = new ComplexData();
    
    // act
    var result = sut.OtherPublicMethod(data);
    
    // assert
    result.Should().Be(1);
}
```